# SQL to Get Latest Field Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write an SQL query (SQL Server) that returns the latest value of a field from a history table.

The table structure is basically as below:

ISSUE TABLE:

```
issueid
10
20
30
```

CHANGEGROUP TABLE:

```
changegroupid | issueid | updated    |
1             | 10      | 01/01/2020 |
2             | 10      | 02/01/2020 |
3             | 10      | 03/01/2020 |
4             | 20      | 05/01/2020 |
5             | 20      | 06/01/2020 |
6             | 20      | 07/01/2020 |
7             | 30      | 04/01/2020 |
8             | 30      | 05/01/2020 |
9             | 30      | 06/01/2020 |
```

CHANGEITEM TABLE:

```
changegroupid | field   | newvalue |
1             | ONE     | 1        |
1             | TWO     | A        |
1             | THREE   | Z        |
2             | ONE     | J        |
2             | ONE     | K        |
2             | ONE     | L        |
3             | THREE   | K        |
3             | ONE     | 2        |
3             | ONE     | 1        | <--
4             | ONE     | 1A       |
5             | ONE     | 1B       |
6             | ONE     | 1C       | <--
7             | ONE     | 1D       |
8             | ONE     | 1E       |
9             | ONE     | 1F       | <--
```

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
issueid | updated    | newvalue
10      | 03/01/2020 | 1
20      | 07/01/2020 | 1C
30      | 06/01/2020 | 1F
```

So each change to an issue item creates 1 change group record with the date the change was made, which can then contain 1 or more change item records.

Each change item shows the field name that was changed and the new value.

I then need to link those tables together to get each issue, the latest value of the field name called 'ONE', and ideally the date of the latest change.

These tables are from Jira, for those familiar with that table structure.

I've been trying to get this to work for a while now, so far I've got this query:

```
SELECT issuenum, MIN(created) AS updated FROM 
(
    SELECT ISSUE.IssueId, UpdGrp.Created as Created, UpdItm.NEWVALUE
    FROM ISSUE
        JOIN ChangeGroup UpdGrp ON (UpdGrp.IssueID = CR.ID)     
        JOIN CHANGEITEM UpdItm ON (UpdGrp.ID = UpdItm.groupid)        
    WHERE   UPPER(UpdItm.FIELD) = UPPER('ONE') 

) AS dummy
GROUP BY issuenum
ORDER BY issuenum
```

This returns the first 2 columns I'm looking for but I'm struggling to work out how to return the final column as when I include that in the first line I get an error saying "Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

I've done a search on here and can't find anything that exactly matches my requirements.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: . . . Side Note : `ONE` is already in Upper Case. So, `UPPER()` is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM (SELECT i.IssueId, cg.Created as Created, ui.NEWVALUE,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.IssueId ORDER BY cg.Created DESC) as seqnum
      FROM ISSUE i JOIN
           ChangeGroup cg
           ON cg.IssueID = CR.ID JOIN
           CHANGEITEM ci
           ON cg.ID = ci.groupid        
      WHERE UPPER(UpdItm.FIELD) = UPPER('ONE') 
    ) i
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY issueid;
```

Comment: . . . Side Note : `ONE` is already in `Upper` Case. So, `UPPER()` is redundant.

Comment: @YogeshSharma . . . This is from the OP's code.  My guess is that the `'ONE'` is really a parameter being passed in or something like that.

Comment: That's helped me a lot, thanks! Yes you're right about the UPPER('ONE') being redundant, I missed that while I was simplifying the query into a format to put on here.